# JS how to find the name of an object using "this" keyword?

Tags: javascript, object, this

i have an object named dogs:

```
const dogs = {
   name: "Murch",
   age: 8,
   says(){
     console.log(`My name is ${this.name}.`);
   }
};
```

Question is: How can i prints "dogs" using "this" keyword?

For example, if i

```
console.log(typeof this);
```

i get "object" but i want to name of the object.

Comment: This sounds like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you think you want to retrieve the name of the variable?

Comment: *"...but i want to name of the object."* Objects don't have names. The names of variables, constants, or properties are not the names of objects. If you want to associate a name with an object, give the object a property that you put the name in, then use that property.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you for explanation. I've been learning JS, your comment and the answer below helped to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the variable to which an object is assigned.

It might be assigned to multiple variables or to none at all.

```js
const dogs = {
   name: "Murch",
   age: 8,
   says(){
     console.log(`My name is ${this.name}.`);
   }
};

const cats = dogs;

cats.says();
```

```js
({
   name: "Murch",
   age: 8,
   says(){
     console.log(`My name is ${this.name}.`);
   }
}).says();
```

Under some circumstances you can search places where an object might be a assigned and look for a match, but `const` variables are not one of those places.

```js
const dogs = {
  name: "Murch",
  age: 8,
  says() {
    console.log(`My name is ${this.name}.`);
  },
  findme() {
    const match = Object.entries(animals).filter(([key, value]) => value === this).pop();
    if (match) console.log(match[0]);
  }
};

const animals = {
  dogs,
  cats: null,
  bats: null,
  rabbits: null
};

dogs.findme();
```